# Альтернатива ключевого слова ref в Java

Tags: java, c#

Нужно адаптировать метод из C# для Java. Как можно заменить ключевое слово ref в данной ситуации?

```
static void Change(int width, int height, int Xl, int Yl, int Xr, int Yr, ref int[,] aMatrix)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
                {
                    aMatrix[Xr + j, Yr + i] = aMatrix[Xl - j, Yl + (width - i) - 1];
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1068760/2881286

Comment: Нет такой альтернативы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806545/does-java-have-something-like-cs-ref-and-out-keywords

Comment: вообще можешь еще попробовать найти конвертор с c# на java, они в природе есть. что-то типа https://www.unisharping.ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в Java сложные объекты ( классы / массивы (примитивов) ) передаются всегда по ссылке.
так что метод может выглядеть примерно так.

```
public class Test
{
    static void Change(int width, int height, int Xl, int Yl, int Xr, int Yr, int[][] aMatrix)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                aMatrix[Xr + j][ Yr + i] = aMatrix[Xl - j][ Yl + (width - i) - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = new int[][]{{1,2,3}, {3,4,5}, {4,5,6}};
        Change(2,2,1,1,1,1, matrix);
        for(int[] raw: matrix)
        for(int value: raw )
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: это не то же самое поведение что с модификатором ref в c#

Comment: ref по сути в C# это аналог & в C++, т.е. передача аргумента(указателя) с неявной адресацией. В Java вообще нет указателей в явном виде, все сложные объекты и так указатели. В данном, конкретном, случае код работать будет абсолютно так же как и код в C#. А вот если бы надо было передать ссылку на целое число, вот тут уже в Java не выйдет так сделать.

Comment: Конкретно в данной ситуации `ref` и в `c#` не нужен. А там где он нужен, java уже ничего не предлагает

Comment: ну почему же предлагает :D например передать вместо out-параметра массив или класс из одного элемента никто не запрещает. Просто это все добавляет багов и нюансов, и с ходу можно наступить на грабли. Java старше, и изменения в нее вносятся не так скоро. из-за боязни потерять совместимость со старым кодом. при создании C# эти нюансы учли. там есть много всего чего в Java не хватает ;(

Comment: Ага :-) Java - сами придумываем сложности и героически их преодолеваем :-)

Comment: ну не совсем, скорее сложности добавляет нам необходимость на ней что-то писать после привычки кодить на "новомодных" .NET("Microsoft Java"), примерно как жаловаться что учился водить на автоматической коробке, а заставляют водить на механике :D.

Comment: @Yakov я как человек в java чуть более года могу сказать легко что порог входа в java на много ниже чем мною любимый c#. Но работая больше года на java могу сказать что нет задач которые не решаются в одной а в другом решается

Comment: Я как программист более 15 летним стажем что механика и автомат это когда вы водите примитивно на более продвинутом уровне вовсе не важно какая у вас коробка. Вы не думаете о переключение скоростей вы решаете задачи

Comment: Вопрос не в том что решается или нет. а в том сколько усилий нужно затратить чтобы получить одинаковый результат в одном и в другом. в джаве аннотации могут творить с кодом через рефлексию всякую дикую дичь которой в c# нет. с одной стороны. с другой в C# код получается всетки ( мое субъективное мнение) читабельней и понятней. и еще что немаловажно, в нем проще оперировать данными на низком уровне ( делать вызовы в WinApi например, или вызовы функций из неуправляемого кода, работать с данными). В яве для этого есть JNI, но блин он требует написания кода на С/С++ и его компиляции и загрузки.

Comment: а это как минимум уже два компилятора в проекте. а на c# это делается все из кода в одном месте без дополнительных оберток.

Comment: Поймите что вы работаете и зарабатываете на решении поставленных задач. У каждой монеты есть оборотная сторона. Еслиб придумали идеальный язык то вопрос давно решили бы но его не придумают и это говорит более универсальный язык математики который тоже не идеальный

Comment: кто-же с этим спорит. просто ява жива потому что она первая кросс-платформенная среда которая заняла нишу в огромном числе устройств от кофеварок до сотовых и серверов в Ынтерпрайзах. А низкая относительно более молодых конкурентов производительность, инертность языка и баги которые не правят из-за боязни сломать старый код это плата за это. Не зря же гугл принуждает всех мигрировать разработку в котлин.

Answer (score 1):

Такой альтернативы нет в [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806545/does-java-have-something-like-cs-ref-and-out-keywords).
Но вам никто не запрещает возращать значения из функции. Собственно передавайте параметр и получайте результат из функции изменив, создав или ещё чего сделав со значениями. Ведь основная идея передачи ссылки это его изменение. Изменяйте и возвращайте в ответе, а его в свою очередь присваивайте.